# Почему происходит ранний выход из цикла?

Tags: javascript, for

Не могу понять почему цикл никогда не проходится по всем элементам массива: если слово из трех букв - он сделает две итерации, если из пяти - 3. Не могу никак усмотреть, даже с помощью дебагера, условие такого выхода из цикла.

```
     const usersWord = prompt('Введите любое слово');
let structureArrayUser = Array.from(usersWord);
let result = '';
for (let i = 0; i < structureArrayUser.length; i += 1) {
  result += structureArrayUser.pop();
}
  if (result === usersWord) {
    alert('Это слово палиндром');
  }
  if (result !== usersWord) {
    alert('Это слово не палиндром');
  }
```

Comment: Выводит промежуточные результаты и смотри

Comment: потому что ты делаешь structureArrayUser.pop() внутри цикла, который уменьшает массив на один элемент

Comment: как-то вы абсолютно неумело пользуетесь дебаггером....если только дебаггер для вас не console.log..... ведь там можно в Watch смотреть переменные и что в них происходит на каждой строке кода...